# Timer не запускает событие Elapsed

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

столкнулся с проблемой, при выполнении метода Start(), не начинает обрабатываться событие Elapsed

```
class Time
{
    DateTime Event = new DateTime(2018, 09, 01, 0, 0, 0);
    public string TimeBeforeTheEvent;
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    public Time()
    {
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan RemainingTime = Event - DateTime.Now;
        TimeBeforeTheEvent = RemainingTime.Days + " : " + 
        RemainingTime.Hours + " : " + RemainingTime.Minutes + " : " + 
        RemainingTime.Seconds;
    }
}
```

Доп. Инфо
Раньше конструктор Time(), был методом, соответственно с другим названием, но результат был тот же
Таймер нужен для создания обратного отчета до события
Вызов из главной формы
Вызов происходит в событии FormLoad

```
Time NowTime = new Time();
```

При создании экземпляра класса, вызывался конструктор таймера

Comment: Как вы поняли, что не запускает?

Comment: @tym32167, Выполнил трассировку кода, при выполнении  метода Start(), который и вызывает метод Elapsed, ничего не происходит, он не "заглядывает" в тело события

Comment: `Start(), который и вызывает метод Elapsed` - это неверно. Метод Start стартует таймер, который вызывает событие OnTimedEvent тогда, когда ему сказали, то есть через секунду. Потому никуда и не проваливаетесь. Ставьте точку останова внутри метода `OnTimedEvent` и вы увидите, что он вызывается.

Comment: @tym32167, Ясно...Просто прочитал описание метода `Start()`, в котором сказано, что он вызывает событие Elapsed. Понятно, он действительно заходит. Напишите ответ наверно, дабы закрыть вопрос. Буду думать, почему он не выводит время, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: [Start() - Starts raising the Elapsed event by setting Enabled to true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) - он не вызывает метод Elapsed, он запускает таймер, который уже вызывает **событие** Elapsed

Comment: @tym32167, Я читал русскую адаптацию, [Метод Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: по вашей же ссылке `Starts raising the Elapsed event by setting Enabled to true.` и `If Start is called and AutoReset is set to false, the Timer raises the Elapsed event only once, the first time the interval elapses. If Start is called and AutoReset is true, the Timer raises the Elapsed event the first time the interval elapses and continues to raise the event on the specified interval.` :)

Comment: @tym32167, Ладно, понятно, буду знать, что этот метод не вызывает Событие Elapsed

Comment: Нет ничего страшного, что поняли не так, такое со всеми бывает. Я потому когда читаю доки сам в каждое слово вчитываюсь.

Comment: @tym32167, ну да, я тем более еще не опытный, так что думаю, это нормально ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ . 4 дня с этим сидел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx) стартует таймер, который вызывает событие OnTimedEvent тогда, когда ему сказали, то есть через секунду. Потому никуда и не проваливаетесь. 
Ваш код рабочий, достаточно поставить точку останова внутри события и убедиться, что оно вызовится через секунду после запуска таймера.